# EF7 generating incorrect sql with optional relationships

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework-core

Consider the following models:

```
public class News
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public Branch Branch { get; set; }
    public int? BranchId { get; set; }
}

public class NewsDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public BranchDto Branch { get; set; }
}

public class Branch
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<News> News { get; set; } = new List<News>();
}

public class BranchDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Here we have an optional relationship between `News` and `Branch` (1-to-many).

We're issuing the following query:

```
context.News
    .Select(dto => new NewsDto()
    {
        Id = dto.Id,
        Title = dto.Title,
        Branch = dto.Branch == null ? null : new BranchDto()
        {
            Id = dto.Branch.Id,
            Name = dto.Branch.Name
        }
    }).ToList();
```

#### EF6

The generated query is:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Title] AS [Title], 
CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[Id] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1], 
[Extent1].[BranchId] AS [BranchId], 
[Extent2].[Name] AS [Name]
FROM  [dbo].[News] AS [Extent1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Branches] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[BranchId] = [Extent2].[Id]
```

This is how it should be: a left outer join after a `CASE WHEN` to handle null references to the `Branches` table.

#### EF7 (RC1)

The same query is generated as:

```
SELECT
[dto].[Id],
[dto].[Title],
[dto].[BranchId] IS NULL,
[dto].[BranchId],
[dto.Branch].[Name]
FROM [News] AS [dto]
INNER JOIN [Branch] AS [dto.Branch] ON [dto].[BranchId] = [dto.Branch].[Id]
```

I don't really understand why this is happening. The relationship is clearly optional so inner joins are just plain wrong. Other than that, the line `[dto].[BranchId] IS NULL` is giving a `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IS'` so I guess this isn't even valid sql.

This is only happening when the relationship is optional. What's going on?

Comment: What are trying to achieve here `[dto].[BranchId] IS NULL`

Comment: I didn't write this line, this is generated by ef7 itself. And yes, it looks like it's invalid sql.

Comment: Did you try the latest (RC2) bits?

Comment: Word is the ef guys have not implemented outer joins as of yet. There are some complexities with that they're trying to solve first. I'm not sure if this is already solved and I didn't have time to try the latest bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I believe this is related to [issue #3186](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3186). The EF team recognizes this as a high priority bug and it should be fixed in `RC2`.